# AJAX navigation that changes the location of the browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, navigation, location

I've been wondering for a while how github.com does it's navigation. If you enter a project in the FF4 (don't know if it works in FF3.6) or Chrome (only two I've confirmed working, haven't tested much more, but it doesn't work in IE9) they have ajax-navigation (the new page is loaded in an ajax-request, and only the new content is exchanged on the client side), still the url changes. And it's not just the hash-part of the url, the actual url changes. How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full explanation from the GitHub team here:

https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider

Answer (score 1):

if you want easy implementation of such navigation,

you could use https://github.com/binarymind/jquery-navigate

to test that, just add in your head after the jquery script :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/binarymind/jquery-navigate/master/navigate.js" ></script>
```

after just read the doc in the github and don't hesitate to ask me if any issue, would be pleased to help

Answer (score 0):

They might be using something like this:

[jQuery, ASP.NET, and Browser History](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/04/08/jquery-asp.net-and-browser-history.aspx)